# Hash Implementation - Hash Function MAD Form

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, implementation

I am implementing a hash table in java and I have to define the hash function. I am following the MAD Form.

I read in internet:

> The MAD method: `h2(y) = [(ay + b) mod p] mod N`, where `N` is the size of the hash table, `p` is a prime number larger than `N`, and `a` and `b` are integers chosen at random from the interval `[0, p-1]`, with `a > 0`.

Which number should be `P`? How larger than `N`?

Comment: it really doesn't matter. most of the library use 31. but the catch is the bigger the better.

Comment: Also see [Why is it best to use a prime number as a mod in a hashing function?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11029/why-is-it-best-to-use-a-prime-number-as-a-mod-in-a-hashing-function) and [Wikipedia: Universal hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing)

Comment: Try [Wolfram Alpha nextprime(N)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NextPrime%5Bn%5D)